# MySQL column info for SELECT command using JOINs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need export data in PHP from general SQL command. To avoid copy pasting I have user friendly column and table names as mysql description. I can get it via `SHOW COLUMNS / EXPLAIN` command. It works well with single table.

But when I need use select joining more tables I can't get column info telling what is source underlying column (table+column, computed, etc.).

```
SELECT * FROM zm_orders o INNER JOIN zm_c_payment p ON o.payid=p.payid
```

Using `DESCRIBE/EXPLAIN` command does provide info about query plan but no info about result (columns).

```
DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM zm_orders o INNER JOIN zm_c_payment p ON o.payid=p.payid
```

Is a way how to dig this info ?

Comment: Have you tried right/left joining ?

Comment: @RobertPounder question is not really regarding which join to use

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want user-friendly column-names that include table-name and/or other information, you cannot use asterisk '*'. You have to name/rename the columns yourself:

```
SELECT o.payid AS o_payid, p.payid AS p_payid FROM zm_orders o INNER JOIN zm_c_payment p ON o.payid=p.payid
```